# Get column name from dynamic query

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a problem and it is taking me too long to solve. I've tried to search a lot of websites, including other questions here at stackoverflow. Nothing works so far.

My problem is: I need to use the SqlQuery() method from Entity Framework in order to make generic queries and return the results in dynamically created objects (using c# Reflection, for instance); the issue is easy to solve when the query specifies the columns to be returned. With those, I can create my object using those column names and everything would work. But when I get a query requesting all columns (like 'select * from mytable') I need a way to get, from the result, the names of the columns, in order that I can access the results.

I have not found a way to do that yet. All the posts and articles I have read on this always assume that I previously know  the structure of the object returned, even those which use Reflection.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

you can do it with a DataTable if i'm correct with the method

```
DataTable.Collumns[index].caption
```

and you can get the count with

```
datatable.collumns.count
```